# Show Popup Screen after you have updated the webpage

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Goal:
When I have updated or added a new data, I would like the to update the webpage and then a popup screen will appear automatically. The text is "test"

THe problem is that I don't knwo how to do it.

Is it possible to do it by using bootstrap, not twitter bootstrap?

Today, I'm using boostrap and asp.net mvc.

http://www.sitepoint.com/twitter-bootstrap-3-javascript-components/

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

    ViewBag.Product = "Test";

    return View();
}
```

[image]

Comment: How are you adding and updating the data? AJAX?

Comment: It takes place inside of backend

Comment: When you have completed updating and adding data. A message needs to inform to the user by using a popup with message "Test".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to persist the message though a new request to the server which you can do many ways. You could use tempdata, session, DB, or pass it to the action manually. I usually use tempdata, which is like ViewBag but lasts through another request:

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

    TempData["Product"] = "Test";

    return View();
}
```

in the view:

```
@if (TempData["Product"] != null)
{
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            @TempData["Product"]
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>$('#myModal').modal();</script>
}
```

This sample code sees if there is a message, if so it will put the modal HTML on the page with your message. There are other ways of doing this too.

Make sure you have bootstrap CSS and JS files referenced on the page before this tiny script runs.